# Multiple image operations in a single process with gm4java

Tags: java, scala, graphicsmagick

This question is about using the gm4java library to interact with Graphics Magick (in scala).

I've been testing the PooledGMService as it is demonstrated [here](http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2013/03/integrate-java-and-graphicsmagick.html) with scala, and it's working well.

However, I noticed that it does not perform similarly to batch mode within the command line interface for gm (`gm batch batchfile.gm`). When I run a gm batch file from the command line with any number of images, it launches 1 gm process. However, if I:

```
val config = new GMConnectionPoolConfig()
val service = new PooledGMService(config)
```

and then share the instance of service across 4 threads, where I perform some operation on one image per thread like:

```
service.execute(
    "convert",
    srcPath.toString(),
    "-resize", percent + "%",
    outPath.toString()
)
```

I see that 4 separate gm processes are created.

I believe this has performance impacts (a test with 100 images, with the code mentioned above against the gm cli with a batch file, takes the same time, but my scala code uses 4x as much CPU).

My question is: how do I use gm4java so that a single gm process is working on several images (or at least several kinds of conversions for the same image), just like the cli batch mode? I've tried a few attempts (some desperately silly) with [no luck here](https://gist.github.com/ilyakava/1486672d367b4b1654ce).

My exact scala code, can be [found here if you are curious](https://github.com/ilyakava/singlet/blob/master/src/main/scala/remote/RemoteMaster.scala#L40).

**update 05/27/14**

With the guidance of a [comment by gm4java's author](http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2013/03/integrate-java-and-graphicsmagick.html?showComment=1400945236718#c5262704435454277517) I realized that I was benchmarking two different gm commands. The updated benchmarking results are:

```
100 x 30MB images (3.09GB tot)
on i7 quadcore (8 logical cpu's w/ hyper-threading)

Criteria            Time
gm cli batchfile    106s
my code 1 thread    112s
my code 4 threads   40s
my code 6 threads   31s
my code 7 threads   31s
my code 8 threads   28s
```

Upon closer inspection, I also saw that while my code ran, the same gm processes with the same process ids were kept up the whole time. This alleviated my worries that I was losing out on performance due to some overhead related to starting and terminating gm threads.

*Rephrasing*

I guess the heart of my question is what to do to make gm4java as fast as possible? The [tip about matching gm the threadcount with the machine's execution engine count](http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2013/03/integrate-java-and-graphicsmagick.html?showComment=1400945236718#c5262704435454277517) is useful. Is there anything else that comes to mind?

My particular use case is resizing input images (30MB is average, 50-60MB occasionally, and 100-500MB very rarely) to a few set sizes (with thumbnails being the most important and highest priority). Deployment will probably be on [amazon ec2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) with 7 or 14 "compute units"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design of [PooledGMService](http://sharneng.github.io/gm4java/doc/1.1.0/org/gm4java/engine/support/PooledGMService.html) is to make max use of your computer power by starting multiple instances of GM processes to process your image manipulation request in a highly concurrent manner. 100 image is a too small sample size to test performance. If your goal is to make best use of your multi-CPU server to convert images, you need to test with large amount of samples (at least few thousands) and tweak the configuration to find the best number of concurrent GM processes to use. See documentation of [GMConnectionPoolConfig](http://sharneng.github.io/gm4java/doc/1.1.0/org/gm4java/engine/support/GMConnectionPoolConfig.html) for all the configuration options.

If you have only 8 CPUs, don't start more than 7 GM processes. If you are testing on a 2-CPU laptop, don't run more than 2 GM processes. In the example, you accepted all the default configuration setting, which will start maximal 8 GM processes upon demand. But that won't be the right configuration to just process 100 images on a merely 2 CPU laptop.

If all you want is to mimic the command line batch mode. Than the [SimpleGMService](http://sharneng.github.io/gm4java/doc/1.1.0/org/gm4java/engine/support/SimpleGMService.html) is your best friend. Look at the usage pattern [here](http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2013/03/integrate-java-and-graphicsmagick.html#SimpleGMService).

The right solution is very much depends on your real use case. If you can tell us more about what exactly you are trying to achieve, your hardware environment and etc, we can be better equipped to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've updated my question with specifics of the use cases. If you have any more tips about speedup tricks, please let me know! As far as I can tell, after rethinking what was going on in my app, PooledGMService still suits my needs best. If I were to instantiate several SimpleGMService connections, I guess I would just slip the responsibility of managing a pool of processes onto myself instead of your optimized library!

Comment: Use "scale" can give you much better performance for thumbnails but the image quality might not be as good as "convert" for larger size images. The number of GM processes to use depends on both CPU and I/O. Start with CPU:GM 1:1 ratio and if your I/O is slow and you see CPUs are not fully occupied, increase the GM Process to make best use of your CPUs. Also you need to watch out memory usage to avoid swapping. If your are optimizing for the throughput, you should also disable GM multithreading (option: -limit thread 1).

Comment: Thank you, I'll do some tests soon on a production machine, trying out multiple SimpleGMService instances, and multiple PooledGMService instances with the 'limit thread 1' option, comparing them to PooledGMService with multithreading.

Comment: @Ilya, You don't need multiple instances of SimpleGMService, you can get multiple connections from the same SimpleGMService. Each connection can execute multiple GM commands. BTW, my comment on the 'limit thread 1' should be added to each command send to GM. GM always use single thread to process the "scale" command. It will use multiple thread to process "convert" command. This is good if you only use single GM process. But if you have all your CPU busy  processing other images with multiple GM processes, allowing GM to use multiple threads will add overhead and reduce the overall throughput.